# React .map only returning first item

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I've just started my React journey recently.  I am currently trying to render properties of an array of objects which is returned from my controller.

The json:

```
[
    {
        "reportID":4,
        "reportDescription":"Commission Bonus Register",
        "reportNotes":"",
        "reportName":"CommissionBonusRegister"
    },
    {
        "reportID":5,
        "reportDescription":"Reset Government ID",
        "reportNotes":"",
        "reportName":"ResetGovtID"
    },
    {
        "reportID":6,
        "reportDescription":"Distributor Chase Up Report",
        "reportNotes":"",
        "reportName":"DistributorChaseUpReport"
    },
    {
        "reportID":7,
        "reportDescription":"Vietnam Distributor Export",
        "reportNotes":"",
        "reportName":"VietnamDistributorExport"
    },
    {
        "reportID":8,
        "reportDescription":"Vietnam Order Export",
        "reportNotes":"",
        "reportName":"VietnamOrderExport"
    },
    {
        "reportID":9,
        "reportDescription":"Distributor List by status and period",
        "reportNotes":"",
        "reportName":"DistributorsList"
    }
]
```

React component code:

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            linkscontent: [],
            loading: true,
            refresh: true
        }
        this.populateReportsLinks = this.populateReportsLinks.bind(this);
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        await this.populateReportsLinks();
    }
  
  render() {
       
        let contents = this.state.loading
            ? <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
            :
            this.state.linkscontent.map(([reports], index) => {
                return <li key={reports.reportID}>{reports.reportDescription}</li>
            });

        return (
            <div>
                <h1 id="tabelLabel" >Reports</h1>
                <ul>
                    {contents}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
       
      
    }

   async populateReportsLinks() {
        const response = await fetch('reports')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data =>
                this.setState({ linkscontent: [data], error: data.error || null, loading: false, refresh: !this.state.refresh }));
       
        return response;
    }
```

After two days of frustration I have finally managed to get the first item to display, but only the first item. Ive read so many articles and forum solutions that seem to indicate this should work. Can anyone help me figure out what is wrong here?

Comment: did you log your return data and check if it's returning data correctly?

Comment: Can you create a code sandbox reproducing this issue? use `Promise.of({...the data})` inttead of fetch to simulate fetch request.

Comment: The issue appears to be that you only saving a single item into your state `this.setState({ linkscontent: [data],`

Comment: Going forward, the way I would debugging this kind of issue doing a console log before your `.map()` function to see what the data is.

Comment: use the spread operator [...data] and I dont think your need the square brackets in the map

Comment: console.log confirms I have 41items in my array as expected.

Comment: Ok thanks guys.  for some reason the square brackets were the only way I was getting anything previously.  removing both [data] and [reports] brackets i now get my list...  using the spread operator just made a big mess :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Remove the `[data]` to just `this.setState({ linkcontent: data, ...restOfUpdates })` after you have fetched your data.
2. While mapping don't destructure with `[reports]` just use the `reports`.

```
    async componentDidMount() {
        await this.populateReportsLinks();
    }
  
  render() {
       
        let contents = this.state.loading
            ? <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
            : this.state.linkscontent.map((reports, index) => {
                return <li key={reports.reportID}>{reports.reportDescription}</li>
            });

        return (
            <div>
                <h1 id="tabelLabel" >Reports</h1>
                <ul>
                    {contents}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
       
      
    }

   async populateReportsLinks() {
        const response = await fetch('reports')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data =>
                this.setState({ linkscontent: data, error: data.error || null, loading: false, refresh: !this.state.refresh }));
       
        return response;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few problems with your logic. Let's look at them one by one.

1. When you set up state with your data

```
this.setState({ linkscontent: [data],...}
```

So when you do the above its basically makes `linkscontent` an array but only of one length. That means on its first index you have `an array` of your data.

2. When you run map like this

```
this.state.linkscontent.map(([reports], index)
```

That means you want to iterate through each index of `linkscontent` but since you have only one index in linkscontent you will get only one item printed.

**How to fix.**

There are a few ways to fix it. You can try saving data into the state as per below code. This will make linkscontent an array with the data source.

```
this.setState({ linkscontent: [...data],...}
Or
this.setState({ linkscontent: data,...}
```

then run map like this

```
this.state.linkscontent.map((report, index) => <li key={report.reportID}>{report.reportDescription}</li>)
```

With your current version of setting `linkscontent` of one length, you can run your map like this as well

```
this.state.linkscontent.length && this.state.linkscontent[0].map((report, index) => ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it comes down to your state not the mapping function. spread the results into an array. this also happens quite often when you incorrectly mutate or update the state.